# vue2 router - access to router link directly without going through root

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

Is it possible to access the specific `router link` without going through the `root`?

I have an app with router below:

```
export default new Router({
    mode:'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
      {
          path: '/about',
          name: 'about',
          component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/About.vue')
      },
      {
          path: '/faq',
          name: 'faq',
          component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "faq" */ './views/Faq.vue')
      },
  ]
})
```

If I go to `www.example.com`, then click on `/about` link, I can go to `www.example.com/about` page. but if I type `www.example.com/about` directly, I will get `404 page not found`. I understand that is because without going through the `root` page, the rest of the `js` file is not loaded yet.

But is there a way for me directly access the page without going through the main page?

Comment: after some digging, found the answer here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations